# HTML5 Canvas: Holding too many canvas object is it expensive?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I am making some simple photo tools which i can move photo around...

If i create a canvas with the same size as background canvas say 800*600 size for every photo added to it and each photo can be rotate move or scale individually in it's own canvas, and draw it on the background canvas.

Holding that number of canvas will it be memory intensive.. assuming 20 canvas of photos.

Comment: It will take as much memory as is needed for those many canvas objects! Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: I have read that having multiple canvas' can help with rendering. Perhaps taking it to the extent of 20 will tip the performance scale in the opposite direction.

Comment: Do you intend do display all the 20 canvas on screen, or have just one screen canvas, store images behind the seen, and drawImage when needed ?

Comment: Yes, twenty 800x600 canvases is a large investment in memory--especially on mobile.  My 2-cents: Use 1 canvas for 20 images and hit-test which image the user is click-selecting.  Then use your tools to transform that one image while leaving the other non-selected images stationary (transform==translate(move), rotate & scale).